# Non-mandatory fields in the search

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this piece of the code intended to search a database. A user should have 3 options here: to type surname only, the first name and the user can search using both of them - surname and the first name.

This code retrieves the records from my db if I provide both strings - surname and the first name. But if I type only one of them, my resulting list is always empty.

```
var query = from x in db.people
                    where (txtSurname == null || x.Surname== txtSurname.Text)
                         && (txtFirstName == null || x.FirstName == txtFirstName.Text)
                    select x;
        var data = query.ToList();
        peopleBindingSource.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that an Entity Framework query doesn't get sent to the database until you materialise the data wth `ToList` or iterating over it for example. This means you can build up the query in code like this:

```
var query = db.people.AsQueryable();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSurname.Text))
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Surname == txtSurname.Text);
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.FirstName == txtFirstName.Text);
}

peopleBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Using this method will likely produce better cached query plans too. You won't get bad indexes due to parameter sniffing from a previous run where most of the fields where not used.

Comment: This is not exactly the same if comparison checking being done in the question.  if (txtSurname == null), you are only checking if (txtSurname.Text).

Comment: @David Yes, but I suspect that is a typo which caused the original problem in the first place.

Comment: David, I tried this solution but I got the warning saying that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyApp.people>' to System.Data.Entity.DbSet... An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast)?"

Comment: David, awesome, it works! Thank you so much.
Best, Lazar